# How can I structure an enumeration using an array?

Tags: enumerate, arrays

I want to structure an enumeration using an array; that is, I want

```
\begin{enumerate}[i]
    \begin{array} {lr}
        \item $a \sim a$ & (reflexivity)
        \item $a \sim b$ then $b \sim a$ & (symmetry)
        \item $if a \sim b and b \sim c then a \sim c$ & (transitivity)
    \end{array}
\end{enumerate}
```

To look something like

```
a ~ a                                                       (reflexivity)
a ~ b then b ~ a                                            (symmetry)
if a ~ b and b ~ c then a ~ c                               (transitivity)
```

Comment: Do you want enumerations (each line numbered?). Do you want this to happen (semi)automatically? Maybe you can use the package `listliketab`.

Answer (score 6):

A slightly customizable environment; I'd avoid pushing the labels all the way to the right margin, because the eye is not good at keeping the direction on a white background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{axiomlist}
\newenvironment{axiomlist}[1][\arabic*.]
 {\flushleft
  \setcounter{axiomlist}{0}%
  \setaxiomlistcount{#1}%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}}
 {\end{tabular}
  \endflushleft}
\def\setaxiomlistcount#1{\setaxiomlistcountaux#1\setaxiomlistcountaux}
\def\setaxiomlistcountaux#1*#2\setaxiomlistcountaux{%
  \renewcommand\theaxiomlist{#1{axiomlist}#2}%
  \def\item{%
    \refstepcounter{axiomlist}
    \makebox[\leftmargini][r]{\theaxiomlist}\hspace{\labelsep}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{axiomlist}[(\roman*)]
\item $a\sim a$ & (reflexivity) \\
\item if $a\sim b$, then $b\sim a$ & (symmetry) \\
\item if $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, then $a\sim c$ & (transitivity)
\end{axiomlist}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{axiomlist}
\item $a\sim a$ & (reflexivity) \\
\item if $a\sim b$, then $b\sim a$ & (symmetry) \\
\item if $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, then $a\sim c$ & (transitivity)
\end{axiomlist}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

The optional argument (default `\arabic*.`) *must* contain a `*` that represents the counter.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you **really** need a version with `array`, it can be done. However, it seems that `tabular` will be more useful and `enumerate` -- useless. (Original code commented, when changed, for clarity).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
%\begin{enumerate}[i] % what for -- PS
%    \begin{array} {lr}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad}l}
%        \item
 $a \sim a$ & (reflexivity)\\
%        \item 
$a \sim b$ then $b \sim a$ & (symmetry)\\
 %       \item 
%$if a \sim b and b \sim c then a \sim c$ & (transitivity)
if $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$ then $a \sim c$ & (transitivity)
\end{tabular}
%    \end{array}
%\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some corrections of spacing are still needed.